# how to reset settimeout when click on set again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use settimeout to change font size of paragraph and when user click on the set again or click on reset button, it starts from the first.

but in my code "reset button" doesn't work and if you click on set again, it starts a new timer and old timer continues with the new one.

Code:

```js
var timer;
jQuery(".set").click(function() {

  clearTimeout(timer);

  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery("p:nth-child(1)").animate({
      fontSize: "18px"
    }, 500);
  }, 1000);

  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery("p:nth-child(1)").animate({
      fontSize: "14px"
    }, 500);
    jQuery("p:nth-child(2)").animate({
      fontSize: "18px"
    }, 500);
  }, 4500);

  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery("p:nth-child(2)").animate({
      fontSize: "14px"
    }, 500);
    jQuery("p:nth-child(3)").animate({
      fontSize: "18px"
    }, 500);
  }, 7500);

  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery("p:nth-child(3)").animate({
      fontSize: "14px"
    }, 500);
  }, 10500);
});
jQuery(".reset").click(function() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

```css
a {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: 000;
}

p {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>first row</p>
<p>second row</p>
<p>third row</p>
<a class="set" href="#">set</a>
<a class="reset" href="#">reset</a>
```

Comment: You're starting 4 timers, and using the same variable for all of them. So `clearTimeout(timer)` only stops the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're creating 4 timers, you need to clear all of them. You can put them in an array and loop over that.

```js
var timers = [];
jQuery(".set").click(function() {

  timers.map(clearTimeout);
  timers = [];

  timers.push(setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery("p:nth-child(1)").animate({
      fontSize: "18px"
    }, 500);
  }, 1000));

  timers.push(setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery("p:nth-child(1)").animate({
      fontSize: "14px"
    }, 500);
    jQuery("p:nth-child(2)").animate({
      fontSize: "18px"
    }, 500);
  }, 4500));

  timers.push(setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery("p:nth-child(2)").animate({
      fontSize: "14px"
    }, 500);
    jQuery("p:nth-child(3)").animate({
      fontSize: "18px"
    }, 500);
  }, 7500));

  timers.push(setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery("p:nth-child(3)").animate({
      fontSize: "14px"
    }, 500);
  }, 10500));
});
jQuery(".reset").click(function() {
  timers.map(clearTimeout);
  timers = [];
});
```

```css
a {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: 000;
}

p {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>first row</p>
<p>second row</p>
<p>third row</p>
<a class="set" href="#">set</a>
<a class="reset" href="#">reset</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using multiple setTimeout, I think using a single setInterval with a count would be a better option, so that your timer would be affected by other timer

```
jQuery(".set").click(function () {

  clearInterval(timer);

  timer = setInterval(function () {
    // every 500ms, count increments
    count++;

    // when time pass 1000ms
    if (count == 2) {
      jQuery("p:nth-child(1)").animate(
        {
          fontSize: "18px",
        },
        500
      );
    }

    // when time pass 4500ms
    if (count == 9) {
      jQuery("p:nth-child(1)").animate(
        {
          fontSize: "14px",
        },
        500
      );
      jQuery("p:nth-child(2)").animate(
        {
          fontSize: "18px",
        },
        500
      );
    }

    // when time pass 7500ms
    if (count == 15) {
      jQuery("p:nth-child(2)").animate(
        {
          fontSize: "14px",
        },
        500
      );
      jQuery("p:nth-child(3)").animate(
        {
          fontSize: "18px",
        },
        500
      );
    }

    // when time pass 10500ms
    if (count == 25) {
      jQuery("p:nth-child(3)").animate(
        {
          fontSize: "14px",
        },
        500
      );
    }
  }, 500);
});
```